# Spark not using spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec

Tags: apache-spark

I'm comparing spark's parquets file vs apache-drill's.
Drill's parquet are way more lightweight then spark's. Spark uses GZIP as compression codec as default, for experimenting I tried to change it to
snappy : same size
uncompressed: same size
lzo : exception

I tried both ways:

```
sqlContext.sql("SET spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec=uncompressed")
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec.", "uncompressed")
```

But seems like it dosen't change his settings

Comment: Did you try setting this parameter in the SparkConf object *before* creating the context? Some parameters are only read at context creation. I also notice an extra dot (".") at the end of the parameter name in the second line - if that's how you tried it and it's not just a copy-paste mistake, it could be the reason..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Worked for me in 2.1.1

```
df.write.option("compression","snappy").parquet(filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

For spark 1.3 and spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec parameter did not compress the output. But the below one did work.

sqlContext.sql("SET parquet.compression=SNAPPY")

Comment: this solution for Spark 1.6.3 did not work for me but this one did. `sqlContext.sql("SET spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec=snappy")`

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Seems to work for me in 1.6.0

```scala
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "uncompressed")
```

Answer (score 1):

For Spark 1.6 :
You can use different compression codecs. Try :

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec","gzip")
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec","lzo")    
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec","snappy")
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec","uncompressed")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "snappy")
```

I see you already did this, but I'm unable to delete my answer on mobile. Try setting this before the sqlcontext as suggested in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

When facing issues while storing into *Hive* via *hive context* use:

```
hc.sql("set parquet.compression=snappy")
```